# How do I convert a 25 hour clock to AM/PM in R?

Tags: r, time

I have a dataset with times that are over 24 hours. How do I convert these times to AM/PM and then order from earliest to latest?

Ex. 25:55 = 1:55 AM (next day)

2:00 AM > 1:55 AM (next day)

Comment: Do you have the format as a string `"25:55"` or in the date time format

Comment: I have it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

I vectorized this in case you actually have a vector.

```
vec <- c("23:02", "24:55", "25:55", "77:33")  # 77 = 24+24+24+5 *shrug*
lapply(strsplit(vec, ":"), function(tm) {
  a <- sum(as.integer(tm) / c(1,60)) %% 24
  sprintf("%d:%02d", as.integer(a), as.integer((a %% 1)*60))
})
# [[1]]
# [1] "23:02"
# [[2]]
# [1] "0:55"
# [[3]]
# [1] "1:55"
# [[4]]
# [1] "5:32"
```

If you want a leading zero for the hour (e.g., `"01:55"`), change the `%d` to `%02d` as well.

**Edit**

Even simpler, since we don't need to make any changes to the minute:

```
lapply(strsplit(vec, ":"), function(tm) sprintf("%d:%s", as.integer(tm[1]) %% 24, tm[2]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "23:02"
# [[2]]
# [1] "0:55"
# [[3]]
# [1] "1:55"
# [[4]]
# [1] "5:33"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use library `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
vec <- c("23:02", "24:55", "25:55", "77:33")

gsubfn("(\\d+):",~sprintf("%02d:",as.numeric(x)%%24),vec)

[1] "23:02" "00:55" "01:55" "05:33"
```

In base R you can do:

```
s=vec

a=regmatches(s,regexpr("\\d+",s))

regmatches(s,regexpr("\\d+",s))=sprintf("%02d",as.numeric(a)%%24)
s
[1] "23:02" "00:55" "01:55" "05:33"
```

or if you do not want to make a copy:

```
`regmatches<-`(vec,regexpr("\\d+",s),value=sprintf("%02d",as.numeric(sub(":.*","",vec))%%24))
[1] "23:02" "00:55" "01:55" "05:33"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers given so far doesn't seem to fully answer the wish for having fully oredered 12-hour times.

```
vec <- c("23:02", "24:55", "25:55", "77:33", "39:56", "08:23", "13:48")
hr <- as.numeric(gsub(":[0-9]{2}", "", vec))

d <- hr %/% 24
h <- hr %% 12
m <- as.numeric(gsub("[0-9]{2}:", "", vec))
p <- c("AM", "PM")[(hr %% 24 > 12) + 1]

times <- data.frame(original=vec, day=d, hour=h, minutes=m, period=p)

times[with(times, order(day, period, hour, minutes)), ]

#   original day hour minutes period
# 6    08:23   0    8      23     AM
# 7    13:48   0    1      48     PM
# 1    23:02   0   11       2     PM
# 2    24:55   1    0      55     AM
# 3    25:55   1    1      55     AM
# 5    39:56   1    3      56     PM
# 4    77:33   3    5      33     AM
```

I'm not used to working with AM/PM, but I think this is how it works.